# mysqldump using a lot of space

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, mariadb, s3fs, mysqldump

I have a server and the `/` partition is 20GB in size.

Databases are stored in `/mnt/mysql-data` partition is 500GB in size.

Now here's the problem. Whenever I run `mysqldump` it fills up `/` partition to 100%. I have already moved the `tmpdir` to `/mnt/mysql-data/tmp`. My databases are around 40GB all in-all now I want to back them up in `/mnt/mysql-data/backups` but I can't proceed because the `/` partition fills up to 100%. my mysqldump command is: `mysqldump --all-databases > /mnt/s3share/backup.sql";`

Server Details:

- 10.2.22-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
- CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  217M  7.6G   3% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda2       24G  2.4G   20G  11% /
/dev/xvda1      976M  168M  757M  19% /boot
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdc1      500G  123G  378G  25% /mnt/mysql-data
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1001
```

```
MariaDB [db_inbox]> show global variables like "%tmp%";
+----------------------------+----------------------+  
| Variable_name              | Value                |  
+----------------------------+----------------------+  
| default_tmp_storage_engine |                      |  
| encrypt_tmp_disk_tables    | OFF                  |  
| encrypt_tmp_files          | OFF                  |  
| innodb_tmpdir              |                      |  
| max_tmp_tables             | 32                   |  
| slave_load_tmpdir          | /mnt/mysql-data/tmp  |  
| tmp_disk_table_size        | 18446744073709551615 |  
| tmp_memory_table_size      | 16777216             |  
| tmp_table_size             | 16777216             |  
| tmpdir                     | /mnt/mysql-data/tmp  |  
+----------------------------+----------------------+  
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

update #1:

I forgot to mention that the `*.sql` backups are being written to `/mnt/s3share/backups/` folder which is mounted as `s3fs` and its cache must be writing to `/tmp` and that may be a reason why `/` is being filled up while the sql dump is being created. However, when I run the backup and watch `/tmp` for changes, it doesn't show any growth. but when I do `lsof` command on `/tmp` I can see huge files being deleted. Could this be it?

Comment: Do you have /var on a separate partition?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille /var is in / partition. but the data is located in separate partition /mnt/mysql-data. there will be data growing in /var whenever mysqldump runs?

Comment: @RickJames 10.2.22-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server

Comment: It sounds like the command is using `/tmp/`.  Look for references to "tmp" in my.cnf.

Comment: @RickJames i already changed it before to go to ```/mnt/mysql-data/tmp``` would it still be using ```/tmp``` despite that?

Comment: Check /var/log , mariadb may be logging too much.

Comment: /mnt/mysql-data/tmp wouldn't be a symbolic link, by any chance?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes i constantly watch du -h on ```/``` partition and ```/var/log``` folder doesn't show any substantial growth.

```/mnt/mysql-data/tmp``` is not a symlink

Comment: Start the dump and when you see free space diminishing, run "find / -xdev -mmin -1 -ls"

Comment: You didn't mention your OS. Your root is elastic, but it doesn't stretch? LOL

Comment: @GerardH.Pille ah i updated a while ago that OS is Centos7. root isn't elastic but there's a mounted /mnt/s3share that uses amazon s3 / s3fs.

Comment: I must have been blind. Let's "see" what the find finds.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i already found the problem, the fuse.s3fs was the one filling up /tmp all along and not mysqldump. already answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to solve this problem by moving the s3bucket cache dir from `/tmp` to `/mnt/mysql-data/tmp`.

Little did I know that `fuse.s3fs` was writing to `/tmp` and there's no way to track which file is growing using `du -h /tmp`

the code I was running was `mysqldump --all-databases > /mnt/s3share/backup.sql` where s3share is mounted using `fuse.s3fs` and has a cache directory targetting `/tmp`. this is why i thought `mysqldump` was causing all the growing storage use on root `/`.

after changing the cache dir of `fuse.s3fs` to `/mnt/mysql-data/tmp`, the problem was solved.

this was my mount command before `/tmp`:

`datastore /mnt/s3share fuse _netdev,allow_other,use_cache=/tmp,passwd_file=$PASSWDFILE 0 0`

then this is the new mount command `/mnt/mysql-data/tmp`:

`datastore /mnt/s3share fuse _netdev,allow_other,use_cache=/mnt/mysql-data/tmp,passwd_file=$PASSWDFILE 0 0`

Comment: Strange how the /mnt/s3share is missing from the list of mounts in your original question.

Comment: yes i never thought it was going to be a main concern. i only realized recently that it could pose a big issue.

Comment: i also added it under the update #1

Comment: That's what makes solving problems on StackExchange a challenge.  Not the problem itself, it would have taken me a couple of minutes, but the contributers holding back information.

Comment: mysqldump -u$DB_USER --lockall-tables=false "$dbname"databases > "/mnt/mysql-datas3share/$dbnamebackup.sql"  was originally mysqldump -u$DB_USER --lock-tables=false "$dbname" > "/mnt/mysql-data/$dbname.sql"

Comment: sorry about that. i was trying to limit information to the most basic i can and i thought it was mainly mysqldump that was causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your innodb_% variables and datadir. There could be something like a tablespace still somewhere else.

Failing that, look at the directory where the root bloat turns up using du while mysqldump is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you use s3fs 1.88 or later, it defaults to flushing the partial file to s3fs every 5 GB, controlled via `-o max_dirty_data`.  This allows uploading files larger than temporary storage.